# Jupyter Notebook, Python3 print function: No output, No error

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Refer to the CODE and OUTPUT below. There is no OUTPUT for the third print statement. An altered print statement in its place such as print(long_word[3:7]) gives output (elin).

```
# [ ] print the first 4 letters of long_word
# [ ] print the first 4 letters of long_word in reverse
# [ ] print the last 4 letters of long_word in reverse
# [ ] print the letters spanning indexes 3 to 6 of long_word in Reverse
long_word = "timeline"
print(long_word[:4])
print(long_word[3::-1])
print(long_word[3:7:-1])
print(long_word[-1:-5:-1])
```

OUTPUT

```
time
emit

enil
```

What gives? The situation of this question also raised in link below. It is unaddressed as of now.

Answer (score 1):

The slice operation in Python is `[start:end:step]`, when `step=-1`, it represents get values in the reverse direction.

So when use `print(long_word[3::-1])`, it is actually from index 3 to index 0 which is determined by reverse direction flag `step=-1`. But when use `print(long_word[3:7:-1])`, it represents from index 3 to index 7 which is not a reverse order and it is a collision.

Comment: Right, so it should be  print(long_word[6:2:-1])  This works. One would expect an error in the above case of collision, no?

Comment: I think it is not an error, as you can use `print(long_word[2:15])` or `print(long_word[3:1])`. It is just not a rational range.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print last four letters in reverse try the below code:

```
long_word = "Characteristics" 

print(long_word[14:10:-1])
```

Result: `scit`

14 is a starting string index
10 is an ending string index
-1 is used to reverse the string one by one

Answer (score 0):

```
long_word = "timeline"

print(long_word[0:4])

print(long_word[3::-1])

print(long_word[-1:3:-1])

print(long_word[-3:-7:-1])
```

This is what I have tried, I think it is an answer of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is:

```
    long_word = "timeline"
    print(long_word[:4])
    print(long_word[3::-1]) 
    print(long_word[-1:-5:-1])
    print(long_word[6:2:-1])

time
emit
enil
nile
```

Note that when reversing, you state the wanted ending index first, then the wanted start index - 1 second(except for the 0 index do not subtract one from it), like so:
 long_word(wanted ending index: wanted start index - 1: -1)

Comment: Can you highlight the neccessary changes?